# fade View IN and OUT

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, core-animation

Good Morning everyone,

I'm totally confused with this problem.

I have 3 UIWebViews and what should hapen is webView1 fades in (that works) fades out und WebView2 fades in......

I made it so far with:

```
CATransition *Animation = [CATransition animation];
[Animation setDuration:4.0];
[Animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[Animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFade];
[Animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];


transitioning = YES;

if (transitioning) {
    [self.webView1.layer addAnimation:Animation forKey:nil];
    self.webView1.hidden = YES;
    self.webView2.hidden = NO;
```

can anyone help me with that?

And when it fades in the webView fades from white even the background color is set to an other color!
can't I effect the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `UIView` implicit animations. For instance, a cross fade from webView1 to webView2:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade" context:nil];
self.webView1.alpha = 0.0;
self.webView2.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If you wanna execute some code after the animation finished, insert this between begin and commit:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(fadeAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

and create the didStop method with the signature

```
- (void)fadeAnimationDidStop:(NSString*)animationID finished:(NSNumber*)finished context:(void*)context`
```

Comment: @Stephen true. I decided for the backwards compatible approach.

Comment: Thanks Ortwin that works so far.
But webView2 should blend in when webView1.alpha is 0 and when i try to blend over to another View it only shows the the transition between the first two?

Comment: @Frank so you want to first fade out webView1, then fade in webView2? In this case, put `self.webView2.alpha = 1.0` in the didStop method. Basically, for each animation that should run after another, you have to define a separate UIView animation. You can bind them together using the didStop selector I described.

Comment: @Ortwin can you explain how do I bind them?
When I try co call the second didStop method inside the first didStop method it is not been fired.
Am I on the complete wrong way?

Comment: @Frank, no, it should actually work. In the first didStop method you can create a new animation setting a different didStop selector. If it doesn't work, please create a new question with the code and reference it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
transition.type =kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype =kCATransitionFade;
```