# fading background while UIWebview has focus

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios6

Is it possible to fade the background of an app (a lightbox type effect) when a `UIWebView` has the focus, keeping the `UIWebView` sharp?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4386998/2106973

Comment: Need more information regarding what you want to achieve.

Comment: Add another transparent view (to achieve the fading effect) in the superview of the webview and bring the webview to the front?

Comment: Thanks Verbumdei -  simple answer that works a treat. Can't accept as a comment, but appreciate it. Thanks to all for advice.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths: I am adding it as an answer then :). Please help to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another transparent view (to achieve the fading effect) in the superview of the webview:

```
[self.view addSubview:transparentView];
```

After that, bring the webview to the front.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webView];
```